# ado.net data service performance

Tags: service, ado.net

I am testing on ado.net data service. I just created web application with SQL server there is one table and about 900 rows in database table. I made a model only contains one entity.

After building application I just test to get all entities from web browser. but it takes about 5 or 6 minutes to get all data in internet webbrowser 
I don't know this is normal situation or not. source table only has 5 columns. 
Do I miss something?

I am working on Visual studio 2008 sp1 and .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you've done, but 900odd rows shouldn't take that long!

maybe you could provide a little more info about your data and / or your connection to the web server?

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I made BMSEntities1.edmx file(entity model file) from sql server with one table. TAII11 entity was made. 
TAII11 entity represents TAII11 database table contain 5 columns and 900 rows. SQL server is running on different server.
And i created ado.net data service with BMSEntities1. I am testing on visual studio development server.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, did you checked your internet connection, data transfer rate, It doesn't look like bug.